# Does Go feature a template language?

Tags: file, templates, variables, go

[In Puppet it is possible to lookup variables in files using ERBs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template_erb.html), e.g.:

> ```
> <% @values.each do |val| -%>
> Some stuff with <%= val %>
> <% end -%>
> ```

How to do the same using Go?

Comment: you mean go's template engine? https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, but Go has a very powerful template engine built in: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

There's even a special HTML extension package of it that does automatic escaping based on context (attributes, tags, text, etc) - https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/

The above example would look something like:

```
{{ range .Values }}
    Some stuff with {{ . }}
{{ end }}
```